# mergeSort for 2d array's 1st index in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, mergesort

I am trying to sort a 2D array based on the value of 0th indexes. I tried modifying merge sort a bit but I am getting this problem where after calling the function only the first element in copied to all indexes.

```
    public static void mergeSort(long arr[][], int s, int e) {
        if (s < e) {
            int mid = s + (e - s) / 2;

            mergeSort(arr, s, mid);
            mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, e);

            merge(arr, s, mid, e);
        }
    }

    public static void merge(long arr[][], int s, int mid, int e) {
        int n1 = mid - s + 1, n2 = e - mid;
        long left[][] = new long[n1][2];
        long right[][] = new long[n2][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            left[i] = arr[i];
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
            right[i] = arr[i + n1];
        }

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = s;

        while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
            if (left[i][0] < right[j][0])
                arr[k++] = left[i++];
            else
                arr[k++] = right[j++];
        }

        while (i < n1) {
            arr[k++] = left[i++];
        }

        while (j < n2) {
            arr[k++] = left[j++];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long arr[][] = { { 1, 4 }, { 3, 6 }, { 8, 4 }, { 7, 7 } };
        
        mergeSort(arr, 0, 3);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i][0] + " " + arr[i][1]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is the initialization of the temporary arrays in the `merge` method is incorrect: you must use a shifted index in `arr`:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        left[i] = arr[s + i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        right[i] = arr[m + 1 + i];
    }
```